# UTF8 codec inválido em python

Tags: python

Estou a usar este código no script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xx", user="xxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="xxxxxxx")    

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT DataConsulta, Dias, HoraConsulta, HoraSaida, nome, Consulta, centrodb.LocalConsulta.Descricao, Contato FROM centrodb.RegistoConsultas LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.LocalConsulta ON centrodb.LocalConsulta.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.`Local` LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.UtentesCons ON centrodb.UtentesCons.codigoutente = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.DiasSemana ON centrodb.DiasSemana.Id = centrodb.RegistoConsultas.DiaSemana")

myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for linha in myresult:
 DataConsulta = linha[0]
 Dias = linha[1]
 HoraConsulta = linha[2]
 HoraSaida = linha[3]
 nome = linha[4]
 Consulta = linha[5]
 Descricao = linha[6]
 Contato = linha[7]

 today = datetime.date.today()
 data = today + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

 if DataConsulta == data:
 ...
```

Mas quando execute o script recebo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é os caracteres que existem na tabela da base de dados com **~**, como posso resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso ocorre por que você realmente está lendo dados que não estão em UTF-8.

No seu caso no erro é possível ver que isso ocorre no caracter 'Ã' e se pesquisar pelo caracter `0xe3` vai perceber que ele é o hexa pra 'ã'. Por isso a mensagem:

> can't decode byte 0xe3.

Adicione na conexão do banco `charset='utf8'`:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.xxx.x.xx", user="xxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxx", db="xxxxxxx", charset='utf8')
```

Comment: está em ANSI. Como altero no IDLE do python 3.7?

Comment: descobri que o problema bem da base de dados, porque umas das variáveis utiliza o ~, como posso resolver?

Comment: @Iniciante, edite sua pergunta ou abra outra com mais detalhes do código e conexão com o BD. Será mais fácil de ajudar você.

Comment: editei a pergunta com o código com a conexão à base de dados e o laço. Depois do if só tem a API para o envio da sms